# Date Picker Parameter for Oracle Apex Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to make an interactive report which as one parameter (a date picker),based on the date selected I want to load/refresh my interactive report respectively and the datepicker item will be submitted to load report.

I have already tried by submitting the datepicker item,used Dynamic Action to Set its event to "change" then set it's true action to "submit page".But No result is displayed.

Here is my report query:

> select * from TRN_SUMMARY  where (:P2_DATE IS NULL) OR to_char(REP_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY')=:P2_DATE;

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it - works fine.

I presume that `WHERE` clause you wrote is invalid. Try without `TO_CHAR` (why would you need it? Date picker *is* a date), e.g.

```
select * 
from TRN_SUMMARY 
where :P2_DATE IS NULL 
   OR REP_DATE = :P2_DATE;
```

Comment: Worked now,after removing to_char!

Comment: Nice; I'm glad you made it.